# IOS: OpenGL Triangle Not Showing up

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I have a GLKViewController that has an implementation as follows...

```
#import "game-gl.h"
....
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
  renderFrameLine();
}
```

game-gl.c ( I started with s = .5)

```
void renderFrameLine() {
    printf("Inside Render Line \n");
    if(f>1.0f){
        f = 0.0f;
    }
    else{
        f = f+.01;
    }
    glClearColor(f, 0.65f, f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    if(s >2.0f){
        s = -2.0f;
    }
    else{
        s = s + 0.10f;
    }
GLfloat vVertices[] = { s, s, 0.0f, s, -s, 0.0f, -s, s,
    0.0f};
GLfloat colors[] = {
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vVertices);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 4);
 }
```

When I run the app the background changes color but the Triangle never shows up. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Problem appears to be with shaders not compiling...

```
shader = glCreateShader(type);
if (shader == 0){
#ifdef __APPLE__
    printf("Shader Failed %d\n", type);
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Prints out that the shader failed (type = GL_VERTEX_SHADER)

I commented this out and I still get the same response, only everything else seems to compile ok...

**UPDATE**

I also see the following warning, I don't think it is related since the compile check passes but....

> /Users/me/Development/test3/test3/game-gl.c:97:46: Passing 'GLbyte [148]' to parameter of type 'const char *' converts between pointers to integer types with different sign

But as I said this check seems to pass...

```
glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled);
if (!compiled) {
```

**UPDATE AGAIN**

Ok now we are getting some where...

```
programObject = glCreateProgram();
if(programObject == 0){
    printf("Invalid program returned \n");
}
```

Prints off that the program is invalid ?!?!?!?

**And Again**

So I changed to try and grab the program in the .m file but it is still 0.

```
if(_program == 0){
    NSLog(@"Still can not create program");
}
else{
    resizeViewport(screenWidth, screenHeight);
    InitializeOpenGL(0, 0, _program);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the GLKViewController you apparently have to set the context before getting the program. Adding this line...

```
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];
```

before initializing the GL made it work.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your shader code?  Are you creating a fragment shader?  Creating a program?  Linking? if thats not compiling, then thats your first problem.  But you can get useful error messages from gl that will help you there.

Besides that, you should enable the attribute pointer before assigning the data.

Also, make sure you're not culling clockwise faces (CCW instead)...  If u have face culling enabled that is.

Comment: I assume by shader code you are referring to where my shaders are loaded. I am loading them in the C file, I am pretty sure the shaders are compiling, I just sw something that lead me to believe that might be happening but it turned out not to be making a difference (another check passes fine after compiling). You can see the attribute pointer being enabled in the code I posted. I binded the attribute in the initialization code. This is a simple test app so I don't believe I have set up culling.